# Exclude File Filter

Tags: java, apache-commons-io

I used the following code to filter files that are having the following extension

```
FileFilter fileFilter= new WildcardFileFilter("*.docx");
File[] sampleFiles= filesDirectory.listFiles(fileFilter);
```

But what if I want the opposite, I want to exclude files that are having this extension.
Currently I have the following code

```
public class FileFilter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File dir = new File("C:\\temp\\filter-exclude");

        File[] files = dir.listFiles(new ExcludeFilter());
        for (File f : files) {
            System.out.println("file: " + f.getName());
        }
    }

    public static class ExcludeFilter implements java.io.FileFilter {

        @Override
        public boolean accept(File file) {
            if (file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith("docx")) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

But not sure if there are classes already for this.
Is there such a class?

Comment: Are you using `commons-io`?

Comment: Yes..the org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.WildcardFileFilter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could compose with the [`notFileFilter`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/filefilter/FileFilterUtils.html):

```
dir.listFiles(
 FileFilterUtils.notFileFilter(
   FileFilterUtils.suffixFileFilter(".docx")))
```

Answer (score 3):

There is not  built-in `FileFilter` implementations that handle common cases such as yours.
To shorter you could use an anonymous class or better a lambda as `FileFilter` is a functional interface such as :

```
 File[] files = dir.listFiles(f -> !f.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith("docx"));
```

Comment: Ohhh so there really is no other class for this that has implemented this functionality already?

Comment: As far as I know, no there is not.

Comment: Ohh okay okay..thanks.. I thought there was something that could help me also.

Answer (score 2):

As you're using `commons-io` already, have a look at [NotFileFilter](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/filefilter/NotFileFilter.html).

Given your use-case, an example looks like that:

```
FileFilter fileFilter = new NotFileFilter(new WildcardFileFilter("*.docx"))
File[] files = dir.listFiles(fileFilter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any specific reason you're not using the `nio` package and instead use the old `io`?

By using the `nio` package you can get your code to shrink considerably. Also you'll be using what is the best tools to operate with file and the filesystem in general. Have a look at the snippet below:

```
var matcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("*.docx");
try {
    DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get("C:\\temp"), entry -> !matcher.matches(entry));
    stream.forEach(path -> System.out.println("file: " + path.getFileName()));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Effectively this does what your code does, using nothing but the out of the box API provided by the `nio` package to list directories and filter files based on their suffix.